# Why do I get mysterious "TypeError: can only update value with String or number"?

Tags: pyephem

This is really bizarre.  If I run this code (as a nose test), it prints "-0:34:00.0" and all is well

```
def test_o1(self):
    observer = ephem.Observer()
    observer.lon, observer.lat = math.radians(73.9), math.radians(40.7)
    observer.horizon = '-0:34'
    print observer.horizon
```

but, if I run this:

```
def test_o2(self):
    location = UserLocation()
    location.foo()
```

where UserLocation is:

```
# Document is mongoengine.Document
class UserLocation(Document):
    [...]
    def foo(self):
        observer = ephem.Observer()
        observer.lon, observer.lat = math.radians(73.9), math.radians(40.7)
        observer.horizon = '-0:34'
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roy/deploy/current/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/roy/deploy/current/code/pyza/models/test_user_location.py", line 82, in test_o2
   location.foo()
  File "/home/roy/deploy/current/code/pyza/models/user_location.py", line 134, in foo
    observer.horizon = '-0:34'
TypeError: can only update value with String or number
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3 and pyephem==3.7.5.2.

Comment: Indeed, `libastro` is a pure-ASCII library, but I will see what I can do to address this in the next version! Thanks for adding an issue to remind me. Meanwhile, calling the `.encode('ascii')` method on your string is an emergency technique you can use to survive for the time being. Define it as a little function called `e()` or something that you can wrap around your strings if you need to!

Comment: I ended up doing str("-0:34"), which works.  Even if you can't "fix" this, if you could at least update the exception message to include "not unicode", that would make things a lot less mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

Arrggghhh.  I figured it out.  My UserLocation source file starts with:

from **future** import unicode_literals

apparently, _libastro insists on ascii strings, not unicode.